# Assigning random value to a parameter in a python program

Tags: python, random, parameters, init

I need to assign a default random value in `__init__()`. For example:

```
import math
import random
class Test:
    def __init__(self, r = random.randrange(0, math.pow(2,128)-1)):
        self.r = r
        print self.r
```

If I create 10 instances of Test, they all get the exact same random value. I don't understand why this is happening. I know I can assign the random value inside the `__init__()`, but I am curious why this is happening. My first guess was that the seed is the current time and objects are being created too close together, and, as a result, get the same random value. I created objects 1 second apart, but still same result.

Answer (score 19):

The value of the default parameter is being set at the time the function is created, not when it is called - that's why it's the same every time.

The typical way to deal with this is to set the default parameter to `None` and test it with an `if` statement.

```
import math
import random
class Test:
     def __init__(self, r = None):
             if r is None:
                 r = random.randrange(0, math.pow(2,128)-1)
             self.r = r
             print self.r
```

Answer (score 5):

The `random.randrange(0, math.pow(2,128)-1)` is evaluated when the function is defined, not when it is called.

Use

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, r = None):
        if r is None:
            r = random.randrange(0, math.pow(2,128)-1)
        self.r = r
        print self.r
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

When you put the expression inside the constructor header (instead of the constructor body) it only gets evaluated once.

Try this in the body:

```
self.r = random.randrange(0,math.pow(0,128)-1)
```

Comment: True when the expression is used to define the default value of the constructor argument, however, generally speaking, other expressions in a constructor will be evaluated every time it's called to initialize an instance.

Comment: @martineau: What other expressions are you referring to?

Comment: @Ethan Furman: Any expressions not used to define the default value of one of the constructor's arguments will be evaluated every time it's called, such as those appearing within the body of the method itself -- such as shown in this answer.

Comment: @Ethan Furman: A function definition is a compound executable statement and default parameter values are evaluated when the function definition is executed. This is explained in the [Function Definitions](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) section of the Python documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The reason all your class instances have the same value for the argument is because its default value is determined only once, when the method definition it is part of is compiled as part of the `class` statement's execution.

Although this is not the use it was designed for, you could use Recipe 20.14 titled [Automatic Initialization of Instance Attributes](http://flylib.com/books/en/2.9.1.390/1/) from the somewhat dated [*Python Cookbook, 2nd Edition*](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007973) to achieve what you want to do.

This is it applied to the sample code in your question:

```
class AutoAttr(object):
    def __init__(self, name, factory, *args, **kwds):
        self.data = name, factory, args, kwds
    def __get__(self, obj, cls=None):
        name, factory, args, kwds = self.data
        setattr(obj, name, factory(*args, **kwds))
        return getattr(obj, name)

import math
import random

class Test(object):
    r = AutoAttr('r', random.randrange, 0, math.pow(2,128)-1)  # default value
    def __init__(self, r=None):
        if r is not None:  # argument value supplied to override default?
            self.r = r
        print format(self.r, ',d')

for i in xrange(5):
    Test()
Test(42)  # override default random initial value
```

Sample output:

```
282,608,676,427,101,189,083,121,399,193,871,110,434
211,475,719,281,604,076,410,306,973,803,289,140,631
86,842,148,927,120,143,765,936,219,265,140,532,918
41,767,122,731,332,110,507,836,985,804,081,250,336
97,993,619,669,833,151,963,441,072,354,430,500,011
42
```

Here's how it works:

The `auto_attr` class from the recipe is a called a [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors). One of them is assigned to a `Test` *class* attribute named `r`. The first time you access this attribute in an instance of `Test` using `self.r`, Python notices it's bound to a descriptor and calls its `__get__()` method with the `Test` instance as an `obj` argument.

The descriptor's `__get__()` method calls the associated factory function and assigns the result to an *instance* attribute with the same name, so that all further references to that attribute through the instance will get its actual value instead of the `Test` class's `auto_attr` descriptor.